# find text that match certain string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find whether the string contains a certain character(s). if it does then output into a file, if it doesn't then output into another file.
My input data looks like this:

```
exchange    security    volume
TO           AAA        193099
TO           AAB        81000
TO           AAH        2310
TO           AAV        1161144
TO           AAVdbh     675000
TO           ABC        98050
```

So far I have tried this:

```
for row in data:
    if 'a' in row['security'] then .....
```

However, I would like to use regex to match the string i.e. if string contains any lower character then ignore.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `if re.search(r"[a-z]", row['security']):`

Comment: Or use `.isupper()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `filter` with `lambda` function if only upper values are required.

```
>>> x = 'PrinOnlyUpperCaseLetter'
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), x)
'POUCL'
```

If you want both but in different list:

```
>>> x = 'PrinOnlyUpperCaseLetter'
>>> upper_list, lower_list = [], []
>>> for i in x:
...     if i.isupper(): 
...         upper_list.append(i)
...     else:
...         lower_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in row['security']:
   if re.search(r"[a-z]", i):
   #add to file 1
```

else:
      #add to file 2